# Why, in 1 Chronicles 8, do the descendants of Benjamin live in Jerusalem?

Tags: genealogy, jerusalem

> **28** These were the heads of ancestral houses, according to their generations, chiefs. These lived in Jerusalem.

also:

> **29** Jeiel the father of Gibeon lived in Gibeon, and the name of his wife was Maacah. **30** His firstborn son: Abdon, then Zur, Kish,
> Baal, Nadab, **31** Gedor, Ahio, Zecher, **32** and Mikloth, who
> became the father of Shimeah. Now these also lived opposite their
> kindred in Jerusalem, with their kindred. **33** Ner became the father
> of Kish, Kish of Saul, Saul of Jonathan, Malchishua, Abinadab, and
> Esh-baal;

(NRSVUE)

I would also note that the pre-Saul lineage mentioned predates the conquest of Jerusalem by David.

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 3):

Though the city of Jerusalem was on the inherited land of Benjamin, the Jebusites controlled the city. The Benjaminites were not able to drive them out, [Judges 1:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%201%3A21&version=NIV&scrlybrkr=384ef516). Therefore the Benjaminites just dwelled with them in the city until David came and conquered it and even then some Jebusites stayed and served David in the city.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is clear from both Josh 15:9 and 18:16 that the city of Jerusalem was either on the border between Benjman and Judah or perhaps just inside the area allocated to Benjamin.  See map below.

Thus, it is not surprising that some Benjamites lived near or even inside the city before it was fully conquered, as recorded in 1 Chron 8.  This was the mistake that many of the early Israelites made (as did Lot) who, instead of removing the local idolatrous inhabitants, attempted to integrate with them.

[image]